# Issues with Forefront for Exchange file filter

Tags: exchange, attachment, microsoft-forefront-2010

I have an issue where I want to strip some image attachments from emails.

Using Forefront for Exchange I can create a file filter rule based on attachment name, type, and size.  This initially seemed promising as I could filter all messages of type PNG with a name of image???.png less than 5K in size.

However, the two problems I can’t figure out how to get around are

1. this rule applies to all messages and I could not figure out how to narrow it down to only specific recipients
2. it looks like the rule would strip the attachment but then replace it with message text indicating the attachment was striped.  I could not find an option to silently strip the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

your objective can be reached by using the exchange management and creating a transport rule 
under Organization Configuration --> Hub Transport Node --> Transport rule .

you will be able to apply a rule to a user , group etc ..
and you will be able to take an action like silently drop which is what you need.

Hope you find this helpful.